# how to hide homepage tab at firefox or google chrome start up?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, mozilla

I have "set a homepage" in the browser. But i want to hide that tab when the browser starts up.
Is there any way we can hide the homepage tab at the startup and let the "tab run in the background".

Comment: If you don't want the homepage displayed, what do you want Firefox to display when it starts? You are starting a browser. If not the homepage, to what are you expecting it to browse?  Please [edit] your question to be a bit more specific, I am unsure as to what you are really asking.

Comment: Is this question really about programming, or are you asking about is there a setting or add-on for Firefox that allows you to do this?

Comment: I don't know why the devote comes?

Comment: While I did not down-vote, I have been tempted to do so. Your question is not clear as to what you are wanting. It appears to be more about how to achieve something using already available options or add-ons, not about programming. As such, it appears to be off-topic for Stackoverflow, but may be more appropriate on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about). Please [edit] your question to be more clear as to what functionality you actual desire and how you are wanting to achieve that.